# How to get the squared symbol (²) to display in a string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to get `²` to show in a string. As an example my output should be inside a `ActiveX` Textbox and should read `R² = 50`.

I've tried the following two statements:

```
Selection.Characters.Text = "R&ChrW(&HB2)&" = " & variable
```

but this displays a `0` as the output in the Textbox. And this:

```
Selection.Characters.Text = "R² = " & variable
```

also displays a `0`.

Comment: What sort of textbox? On a UserForm, ActiveX control, Forms control, in a Msgbox etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what kind of text box you are refering to. However, I'm not sure if you can do this in a text box on a user form.

A text box on a sheet you can though.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "R2=" & variable
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 1).Font.Superscript = msoTrue
```

And same thing for an excel cell

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Characters(2, 1).Font.Superscript = True
```

If this isn't what you're after you will need to provide more information in your question.

EDIT: posted this after the comment sorry

Comment: Sorry it is in on a textbox on the worksheet, which I'm assuming is userform? I inserted the textbox using excel and assigned it a name, I'm then trying to use vba to insert a string into it. "ActiveSheet.Shapes("Spring_Calib_Textbox").Select"

Answer (score 1):

No need to get too complicated. If all you need is ² then use the unicode representation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

(which is how I assume you got the ² to appear in your question. )

Answer (score 0):

I create equations with random numbers in VBA and for x squared put in x^2.

I read each square (or textbox) text into a string.

I then read each character in the string in turn and note the location of the ^ ("hats")'s in each.

Say the hats were at positions  4, 8 and 12.

I then "chop out" the first hat - the position of the character to be superscripted is now 4, the position of the other hats is now 7 and 11.
I chop out the second hat, the character to superscript is now at 7 and the hat has moved to 10.
I chop out the last hat .. the superscript character is now position 10.

I now select each character in turn and change the font to superscript.

Thus I can fill a whole spreadsheet with algebra using ^ and then call a routine to tidy it up.

For big powers like x to the 23 I build x^2^3 and the above routine does it.

Comment: The technical term for the hat is "caret"